# How to add Header Content-type to static pages which doesn't have extensions?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a XML page www.example.com/page, but my server outputs it as text/plain as it doesn't have any extension.

So I want to add XML Header via .htaccess to all the files which doesn't have extension with a condition that the **file exists**.
As if file doesn't exist, program is executed from database and it decides what header to output, so I don't want to break that part by forcibly changing header.

Comment: Using mod_rewrite create a rule which will add such header using `[T]` flag: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_t . Alternatively, use `<FilesMatch>` directive to match those specific files, e.g. `<FilesMatch "somefile$">`

Comment: `<FilesMatch "^[^\.]*$">
Header set Content-type "application/xml; charset=utf-8"
</FilesMatch>`
is working, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `DefaultType text/xml` (or whatever type you're using for your XML) to your `.htaccess`.

Comment: I need to add `; charset=utf-8` also, any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Other command you can put in your .htaccess (but it will force all files to have this content-type):

```
ForceType text/xml
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_mime.html#forcetype

Comment: For charset you can use `ForceType 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'` or `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8`